# Why, under Black-Scholes, do returns exceed one $\sigma$ every three days, approximately?

Tags: black-scholes

My book claims the following:

> "The other assumption of normally distributed returns would mean that returns would be between $-\sigma$ and $+\sigma$ with 68.269 per cent probability. This means that you would have an exceedence of roughly once every three days."

Now, since $\ln (S_T/S_0)\sim N((\mu+\dfrac12\sigma^2)\Delta t , \sigma^2\Delta t)$, it is immediately true that$$ P\Big((\mu+\dfrac12\sigma^2)\Delta t-\sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}\leq\ln (S_T/S_0)\leq (\mu+\dfrac12\sigma^2)\Delta t+\sigma \sqrt{\Delta t}\Big)=68.269\%. $$
I'm trying to reduce this to "once every three days" but I don't see how.

Comment: If it's in between with 68.269% probability then it's out (not in between) with 100% - 68.269% prob, ie, aprox 0.32%, which is also aproximately "one in every three"

Comment: @DavidDuarte ah I was making it too difficult... Thanks!